# How to write under an underline?

Tags: text-decorations

I would like to be able to write under the underline. Is it possible?

[image]

This is the simple code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{ \textrm{Text}}{1} \frac{\textrm{Text}}{2} \frac{\textrm{Text}}{3}$
\end{document}
```

It does the job but I want to be able to make the texts under underlines smaller. One way to do so is to adjust the font each time. Is it an easier way? Or is there any built-in function for this. To assign the size which would be the same as the size for subscript.

Comment: But do you want the underline aligned with the baseline?

Comment: @Sigur, I didn't quite understand what you mean but I want it to appear exactly as it appears in the example above only with a smaller size.

Comment: Or even better with the size of a subscript.

Comment: Try `\displaystyle` `\textstyle` `\scriptstyle` `\scriptscriptstyle`. These are all fixed sizes.

Comment: I asked if you want the horizontal line aligned with the other words before and after your fraction. For example, if you use `\underline{Text}` the line will be almost in the same height as the text line.

Comment: @Sigur, yes I want it to be at the same height.

Comment: @Naji, fraction is not a solution to you.

Comment: @azetina, thank you but that would require to use `frac` which is not quite related to what I want to do and manually enter the textstyle every time I want to make such an underline, which is quite a lot in my case.

Comment: this can help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122121/14757

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always a good idea to [write repetitive things in a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\underwrite}[3][]{% \underwrite[<thickness>]{<numerator>}{<denominator>}
  \genfrac{}{}{#1}{}{\textstyle #2}{\scriptstyle #3}
}
\begin{document}

See $\underwrite{\text{Text}}{1}\ 
  \underwrite{\text{Text}}{2}\ 
  \underwrite[2pt]{\text{Text}}{3}$.

\end{document}
```

The above MWE uses [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\genfrac` to create a fraction with `\textstyle` numerator and `\scriptstyle` denominator. You can, of course, add other functionality to it (like detecting the mode it's in and adjusting the size accordingly, say). Using `\genfrac` has the advantage of setting the fraction rule thickness; provided as an optional argument when using `\underwrite[<thickness>]{<numerator>}{<denominator>}`.

As reference, see section **4.11.3 The `\genfrac` command** (p 14) in the [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).

Comment: Considering the fact that a simple vote up is not enough for thank you I just want to add that thank you very much indeed for such a thorough answer.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Hello \(\underbracket[0.3pt][0pt]{\textrm{my}}_{1}\) \(\underbracket[0.3pt][0pt]{\textrm{your}}_{2}\) \(\underbracket[0.3pt][0pt]{\textrm{our}}_{3}\)World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: But can't I get rid of the trouble of adding `\underbracket[0.3pt][0pt]` every time?
Do I have to make a command?

Comment: A command would suffice @Naji

Comment: For example: `\newcommand{\su}[2]{\underbracket[0.3pt][0pt]{\textrm{#1}}_{#2}}` @Naji

Comment: @azetina, why do I get an error when I enter this:
`\su{ao_t}{j}` but `\su{ao}{j}` works fine?

Comment: underline `_` is only for math mode.

Comment: `\textrm` is in textmode and you are inputing something that requires mathmode `ao_t`. Fix: `\su{$ao_t$}{j}`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
\small{}
```

or

```
\tiny{}
```

to decreaase the size of your text.

Below is the improved version of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{ \textrm{Text}}{\small{1}} \frac{\textrm{Text}}{\small{2}} \frac{\textrm{Text}}{\small{3}}$
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Omid1989, if you see the history of edits you'll see that I had done it for you before.

Comment: @Sigur, why did you deleted one of the "l"s from my answer !!?

Comment: @Omid1989, if you see the history, I only edited the line at the beginning, not the command on the example.