# How to adjust the alignment of a mathematical expression in a text section? e.g. argmax

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, subscripts

I am using the following definition to generate the `argmax` operator:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
```

However the problem is when I use it in a part that some text exists because of the written argument under `argmin` the next line appears with a abnoraml distance in order to keep the distance from the argument under argmin. However when I use `\frac` for example, this time, the proportion adjusts itself to not to overlap with the next line. How can I change the above command to behave like the `frac`?

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}

\begin{document}
  This is a test. This is a test. $\argmax\limits_{x}{x^2}$ This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
\end{document}
```

With output [image]

As opposed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}

\begin{document}
This is a test. This is a test. $\frac{x}{x^2}$ This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
\end{document}
```

With output[image]

Comment: You might want to try `$\argmax_{x}{x^2}$` instead of `$\argmax\limits_{x}{x^2}$`.

Comment: Thanks, I know that one but I do like to represent `argmax` in this format.

Comment: This is the same behavior when you use `\lim_{i=1}^n` in displaystyle.

Comment: Mhhh, you could `\smash{...}` the whole thing, but that definitely does not look right. Is there no way you could accept the right subscript? (Note that the output of `\frac` in text style is not optimal either.) BTW: you can define `argmax` via `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}`, no need for `\arg\!\max`.

Comment: Since you have an operator with symbol a text it is strange if it is not aligned with the baseline.

Comment: You can do *slightly* better using `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\smash{\text{argmax}}}`, which removes the descender depth from the operator.

Comment: @Naji If you look closely, the fraction is typeset in a very different way: both the numerator and the denominator are smaller and the fraction line is raised from the baseline; nothing of this kind is possible with `\argmax`.

Comment: @Sigur, I actually think this is strange to shift the whole line rather than adjusting the font or alignment of mathematical operator to fit to the line.

Comment: @egreg, I see. However I was thinking of doing something non-standard like Werner's answer here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141932/how-to-write-under-an-underline

i.e. defining a `\genfrac` with thickness zero?!

Comment: @Naji Since you can't reduce the size of “argmax” there's nothing you can do; setting the limit on the right in inline formulas is a widely used practice.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you want to manually correct the vertical spacing, making it closer to this without your operator. I am afraid that the result will not be beautiful. An example of such a solution is the following (vertical spacing chosen by hand):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}



\begin{document}


  This is a test. This is a test. $\argmax\limits_{\raise3pt\hbox{$\scriptstyle x$}}{x^2}$ \vspace{-5pt}
 This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.  This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
\end{document}
```

[image]